# In Rails, how do I query my database from JavaScript so I can save the value of the query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to make a query given the id of my book in javascript and not fetch all the books from the database, for example:

I usually do it like this:

In my **book controller**, I make a query the collection of books and then pass it to the view through a variable:

```
# books_controllers.rb
before_action :set_books
... 
def set_books
  @books = Book.all # here is my books collection
end
```

In my form view I define a variable to store the collection of books, in a **books_info**
variable:

```
#books/form
javascript:
   let books_info = #{@books.to_json.html_safe};
```

And finally, the collection of books is scanned and compared with the id that the client gives me to find the specific information of said book.

```
    Array.from(books_info).forEach((element, index) => {
      if (element["book_id"] === client_book_id){
        new_book_id = element;
      }
    });
```

The problem with doing all that is that I compromise all the book information in views

Simply what I am looking for is given the id of the client (**client_book_id**) to do this in javascript

```
javascript:
  let client_book_id = #{Book.find(´client_book_id´).to_json.html_safe} # This not work but I try to got it.
```

If you could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: this already has answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988512/in-rails-how-to-make-a-query-in-javascript. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the book ID to the **query string** of the URL, e.g. `?book_id=123`
2. The Rails **controller** reads the ID as e.g. `params[:book_id]`
3. The controller sets an **instance variable**, e.g. `@book = Book.find(params[:book_id])`
4. The Rails **view** sets the JS variable using `.to_json` as already shown in the question

This is just one application design, good for beginners. Other designs include XHR (intermediate) or GraphQL (advanced).

Comment: Thanks for your time in responding. But what I'm looking for more than anything is to embed a rails query in javascript with a random ID (in this case the ones from the book)

for example: 

javascript:
var my_client_book = #{Book.find(200).to_json.html_safe}; # this work but i shoud not know the id

#{Book.find(client_book_id).to_json.html_safe}; # This is what I'm trying to detect the client_book_id to make a query into javascript

with query string it does not work for me since I have a dynamic search engine that looks for the book without the need to refresh the page

Comment: I finally ended up using XHR but your explanation is very good. Thank you very much for your time and answer.